# php f(open) works in xammp on windows, but Ubuntu just quotes

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, html-table, fopen

The following works great running xampp on Windows machines however it will not pull in Ubuntu. I have permissions that I know of in the /var, /www and /html. It shows I have read/write in the properties.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>service</title>
<script src="tablefilter/tablefilter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Service Special Orders </h1>

<table id="demo">

<tbody>
<?php
$fp = fopen ( "Service.csv" , "r" );
while (( $data = fgetcsv ( $fp , 1000 , "," )) !== FALSE ) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $data[0] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $data[1] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $data[2] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $data[3] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $data[4] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $data[7] . "</td>";
echo "/<tr>";
}
fclose ( $fp );
?> .....
```

Here's how it looks on Xampp:

[image: xampp]

Here's how it looks on Ubuntu:

[image: ubuntu]

where do I start on fixing this?

Comment: It looks like PHP isn't running on your Ubuntu Server...

Comment: bingo... thanks. installed php7...i was misinformed that php came with the install.